# Make DisclosureGroup non expanable

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm adding one DisclosureGroup inside another DisclosureGroup
I want the second Disclosure group to be non expandable(Remove the ability to expand).
Is that possible or is there a better way to achieve this?

```
@discardableResult
private func expand(key: String) -> Binding<Bool> {
    return Binding<Bool>(
        get: { expanded.contains(key) },
        set: { isExpanding in
            if isExpanding {
                expanded.insert(key)
            } else {
                expanded.remove(key)
            }
        }
    )
}


DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: expand(key: "Incomplete")) {
    ForEach(Array(array), id: \.self) { key in
        if let innerArray = innerArray {
            // Make non expanable
            DisclosureGroup {
                ForEach(Array(tasks.enumerated()), id:\.1.title) { (index, check) in
                    // Content
                }
            } label: {
                // Header
            }
        }
    }
} label: {
    // Header
}
```

Comment: please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You code has a lot of unknown entities

Comment: Hi, I just updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: ok why would you use `DisclosureGroup` is you don't wanna it to be expandable? Won't it mean that there's only `label` will be visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a constant `Binding` set to `true`. This will keep it permanently expanded.

If you want it permanently collapsed (not sure why you would want that) use `false` instead.

```
DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: .constant(true)) {
    // Content
} label: {
    // Label
}
```